# Facing issues on updating magento in magento cloud, updating magento to latest version of magento 2.3.2

Tags: php, git, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

Right now we are working on updating magento to latest version of magento 2.3.2
right now we are runing 2.2.7.

I following the guide for 2.3 branch found at
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/project/project-upgrade.html

I have taken following steps :

Step1: Update ece-tools version

1. On local workstation, perform an update using Composer

> composer update magento/ece-tools

2. Add, commit, and push code changes.

> git add -A && git commit -m “Update magento/ece-tools” && git push origin

Step2: Back up the database

1. Create a local backup of the remote database.

> magento-cloud db:dump

when i run this command in my terminal i get
‘magento-cloud’ is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

2. Back up code and media.

> php bin/magento setup:backup –code [–media]

To back up Staging or Production environment database before deploying

> php vendor/bin/ece-tools db-dump

Step3: Complete the upgrade

I have PHP 7.1.30 version

1. Before completing the upgrade, update the autoload property
   I follow all the steps giving in
   https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html#update-autoload
2. set the upgrade version using

> composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.2 –no-update

3. Then Update the project

> composer update

After composer update i get some error

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
- magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.2.7 requires magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.2.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

- magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.2.7 requires magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.2.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

- Installation request for magento/magento-cloud-metapackage >=2.2.7 <2.2.8 -> satisfiable by magento/magento-cloud-metapackage[2.2.7].
```

can you please guide me how can i solve this issue..

Thanks.

My composer.json like as

```
{
"name": "magento/project-enterprise-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Enterprise Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.3.2",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"repositories": {
    "repo": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
    },
    "amasty": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://composer.amasty.com/enterprise/"
    }
},
"require": {
    "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage": ">=2.2.7 <2.2.8",
    "gene/bluefoot": "^1.0",
    "amasty/promo": "^2.2",
    "sashas/bug-from-email": "^2.0",
    "amasty/shopby": "^2.11",
    "amasty/label": "^1.10",
    "connectpos/rest-api": "^1.1",
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.2",
    "magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.3.2"
},
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": [
            "app/code/",
            "generated/code/"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "**/dev/**",
        "**/update/**",
        "**/Test/**"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"prefer-stable": true,
"extra": {
    "magento-force": true,
    "magento-deploystrategy": "copy"
},
"require-dev": {
    "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.13.0",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
    "magento/magento-coding-standard": "~1.0.0",
    "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "~2.3.14",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.3.1"
}}
```

[error command line screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9BT1.png)

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove

```
 "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.2",
 "magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.3.2"
```

from composer.json, will be installed as dependencies of `magento-cloud-metapackage`

and change metapackage version

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch php to php 7.2  or greater . Because from magento 2.3.2 , it requires php version >= 7.2

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update magento/magento-cloud-metapackage as well with a compatible version of Magento 2.3.2.

I found one article https://technicallysound.in/magento-2-upgrade-and-composer-issues/ that tried to solve similar issues during the Magento upgrade. But it is for the Community edition. Anyway composer issues are similar. In case the article could help you check for an updated version of the magento/magento-cloud-metapackage.

Answer (score 0):

Your `composer.json` should be the same as [magento/magento-cloud/composer.json](https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud/blob/2.3.2/composer.json)